# Является ли в оракл доках Executor executor = anExecutor опечаткой или стандартным сокращением?

Tags: java, многопоточность, документация

Сегодня у нас java. Тема интерфейс Executor. Мы открываем [оракл док](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) , а там пишут:
*... для всех задач вы можете использовать:*

```
 Executor executor = anExecutor;
 executor.execute(new RunnableTask1());
 executor.execute(new RunnableTask2());
```

Пруфпик:

[image: Пруфпик]

Меня смутило то, что `anExecutor` ранее на странице не была задекларирована как ссылочная переменная.
Взял `ctrl+c ctrl+v`  и вставил в IDE -> действительно, код не работает.

**Вопрос:** это просто опечатка в оракл (как вариант, сотрудник пару предыдущих строк не опубликовал на странице) или может быть `anExecutor` какое-то стандартное сокращение, принятое в оракл?

Comment: Курсивом в документациях выделяется то, что вы должны подставить самостоятельно, в данном случае вы должны сами добыть откуда-то объект с интерфейсом Executor и подставить его вместо *anExecutor* чтобы выполнить пример

Comment: Вообще, артикль «an» позволяет перевести *anExecutor* как *какойНибудьИсполнитель* (а какой — это уж решайте сами)

Comment: @andreymal не знал что ларчик так просто открывается. Если у вас есть ссылка на доки, где чёрным по белому написано, что курсив - это то, что мы должны самостоятельно подставить, то дайте как ответ и ответ принят.

Comment: Не знаю, описано ли это где-то конкретно в документации джавы, просто это довольно стандартное обозначение, которое я встречал во многих документациях и книгах

Comment: @andreymal даже не в java. Может если у вас есть ссылка на стандарт, к примеру IEEE где курсивом обозначается это самое - тоже сгодится. Я вообщем то мозгами понимаю что вы правы. Но всё равно нужно подкреплять пруфлинками позицию.